# How do I find a relation for these polynomials from a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I have the following three polynomials: $1 + 2t^2, 4 + t + 5t^2, 3 + 2t$. I need to show that they are linearly dependent in $\mathbb P_2$ (polynomials of degree at most $2$).

I put them in a $3x3$ matrix, and reduced it to a matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -5\\ 0&1& 2\\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

I know they are dependent since row 3 is zero, but how can I find the following relation (given by the book): $3 + 2t = 2(4 + t + 5t^2) -5(1+2t^2)$

Comment: If $A$ is the matrix and $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is a column vector. Then you can solve the system $Ax=0$ and the $x_1,x_2,x_3$ give you the coefficients of the linear combination.

Comment: How did you obtain this matrix ??

Comment: I put the polynomials into matrix form and reduced it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zero linear combination of the given vectors (polynomials) is equivalent in your matrix formulation to a vector in the kernel of the matrix you produced by adjoining the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ corresponding to the given vectors.

Now, the kernel does not change under row operations, so one can produce a zero linear combination $$c_1 (1 + 2t)^2 + c_2(4 + t + 5t^2) + c_3(3 + 2t) = 0$$ simply by finding a vector $(c_1, c_2, c_3)^T$ of the row-reduced matrix you've produced. Here, $c_3$ is free, and taking it to be, e.g., $1$, gives $c_1 = 5$, $c_2 = -2$. Substituting gives $$5 (1 + 2t)^2 - 2(4 + t + 5t^2) + (3 + 2t) = 0.$$
Rearranging gives the particular linear combination you mentioned, and note that we can produce other nontrivial linear combinations by multiplying the combination by some nonzero constant $\lambda$ (equivalently, choosing $c_3 = \lambda$).

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have 3 polynomial's $$p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x)$$

and you want to find 3 scalars $$ \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$$ so:

$$\alpha_1*P_1 + \alpha_2*P_2(x) + \alpha_3*P_3(x) = 0$$.

now if:

$$P_1(x) = a_2*x^2 + a_1*x + a_0$$

$$P_2(x) = b_2*x^2 + b_1*x + b_0$$

$$P_3(x) = c_2*x^2 + c_1*x + c_0$$

then we get the System of linear equations:

$$\alpha_1*a_2+\alpha_2*b_2+\alpha_3*c_2=0$$

$$\alpha_1*a_1+\alpha_2*b_1+\alpha_3*c_1=0$$

$$\alpha_1*a_0+\alpha_2*b_0+\alpha_3*c_0=0$$

then you can put them in a matrix and solve them just like any other set of equations.

in you'r case you got:

$$\alpha_1-5*\alpha_3=0$$

$$\alpha_2+2*\alpha_3=0$$

and $$\alpha_3=1,  \alpha_1=5,  \alpha_2=-2$$ will solve it.

this procedure can be done above any field and with any amount of polynomial's  of any degree.